# How to upload files with additional file data in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, multipartform-data, aurelia

I am trying to upload multiple files (documents) with additional data per file.
Ie. I would like to upload multiple documents like this:

```
[{
  documentFile: file
  documentVersion: 2,
  documentOperation: "createNew"
  ...
 },
 {
  documentFile: file2.doc
  documentVersion: 1,
  documentOperation: "createNew"
  ...
 }]
```

And ideally would like that information to be populated in the model but this is not a requirement.

I am using Aurelia Fetch client to send data using FormData.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is like:

```
public class Documents
{
    public IFormFile documentFile { get; set; }
    public string documentVersion { get; set; }
    public string documentOperation { get; set; }
}
```

You can see my test.

Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Demo(List<Documents> documents)
    {
        //...
    }
```

Send data by postman:

[image]

Result:

[image]